# Is there any API to fetch an iPhone's internal data?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone, ios4

With iPhone's internal data I meant, for example, in general setting we have an option called usage which shows the amount of bytes that has been sent and received. I want to fetch the amount of data that has been sent and received. Can any one help me in this?

Answer (score 0):

The iOS SDK only exposes a minimal set of device specific information. Most of this can be found in the [UIDevice Class](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html).

You can of course determine the network activity of your application, but I doubt that is what you are looking for.